# Codeigniter get value from ajax dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Can anyone help me to get the selected value from an AJAX dynamic dropdown?

I have a dynamic dropdown using AJAX and I want to post the selected value from a second dropdown so that I can filter data.

This is the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#AREA").change(function(){
                  /*dropdown post *///
                    $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/distribusi/filter/buildDropArea",
                    data: {area: $(this).val()},
                    type: "POST",
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#rayon").html(data);
                    }
                 });
               });
            });

   </script>
```

this is the **view**

```
<label for="AREA">AREA</label>
     <?php echo form_dropdown('AREA', $areaDrop,'','class="form-control" id="AREA" ' );  ?>

                       </div>

                       <div class="form-group">

                       <label for="RAYON">RAYON</label>
                       <select name="rayon" id="rayon" class="form-control" >
        <option value=""></option>
        </select>
        </label>
        </div>
```

The problem is I want to send selected value from second dropdown

Comment: Please explain farther... Can you add some html so that we will have some visualization?

Comment: @NeilVillareal how will html help when issue is related to ajax?

Comment: @charliefl It will help me know if he/she have the comboxes in the same page or not.

Comment: @charlietfl it can also help in confirming it the second dropdown already have the data on the first dropdown or not.

Comment: @masitha what value you are getting in response data ?

Comment: can you provide the contents of your controller method?

Comment: $post_area = $this->input->post('area');
$post_rayon = $this->input->post('rayon');

$array = array(
  'AREA' => $post_area,
  'RAYON' => $post,
  
  );

$data['pelayanan'] = $this->model_pelayanan->daftar_all_dist($array);

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the post param `area` but looking for a param named `rayon`

```
$this->input->post('rayon');
```

Should be

```
$this->input->post('area');
```

To be sure you can always do a dump of `$this->post()` and see what gets returned. Any request can be inspected in browser dev tools network tab to see what is sent, status, what is returned, headers etc. Always start there when debugging ajax

Comment: When I used `$this->input->post('area');`, it returns all data in combo box "area". But I want it returns data based on combo box "area" and combo box "rayon"

Comment: really not clear what you are saying. It sounds like your controller code needs changing to send proper data

Comment: I mean I have dynamic dropdown named "area" and "rayon", where the value in "rayon" is depend on selected value in "area". I want to filter data based on selected value in "rayon". How can I do that?

Comment: You are sending the value of `area` so that you can get the proper options for `rayon`. You need to use `area` value to get that data in your controller. Your last comment also has conflicting statements in it which is confusing

Comment: I've got the proper option for "rayon". But I don't know how to send the value of "rayon"

Comment: What you are now asking and what your code shows and what you said a few comments ago are conflicting. Your code shows that rayon options are dependent on area. I am not understanding now what you mean by get the value of rayon. Does `rayon` already have a value and you want to set it after the new html arrives?

Comment: if you want rayon value it's `$('#rayon').val()`

Comment: Yes, the code shows that rayon options are dependent on area. I mean  how can I send the option that I choose in rayon?

I'm sorry my English is bad